# Problems with wp_enqueue_script in WordPress

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I am quite new to WordPress and coding in general, so bear with me. I have two separate files of code one with all the php and another with all the JavaScript. I need the php to read the JavaScript but when I look in the console of the browser it can't find the file. It appears to be looking in the wrong folder so it won't find it anyways.

Here is the code that I have used to try get it to read the JavaScript file

```
function wpdocs_theme_name_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'pq-forms-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/pqnewsletterform.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
}
```

I've tried to change `get_template_directory_uri` to `get_stylesheet_directory_uri` but that did nothing.

Any suggestions on how to fix this problem would be much appreciated.

Comment: what is the file path of your js file?

Comment: @Vel it's WPContent/plugins/forms/newsletter.js

Comment: then do not use `get_stylesheet_directory_uri`

Comment: please check my answer

Comment: @Vel was get_template_directory_uri the correct one to use then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code.

You need to use `plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ )` instead of `get_stylesheet_directory_uri`.

```
function enqueue_scripts() {
  wp_enqueue_script( 'form-js', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'pqnewsletterform.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0.0', true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_scripts');
```